# No adapter for endpoint while using JAXBElement with packagesToScan property on Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, spring, exception, jaxb

I am using JAXBElement<...> because of missing ***@XmlRootElement*** annotation in generated classes for given XSDs (which I cannot modify) but Spring is still giving me the java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [...]. Marshaller is defined as follows:

```
<bean id="marsh" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <propety name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.*.schemas" />
</bean>
```

In the log I can see that spring has loaded all schemas, if I trace to endpointMap on startup I can see it there, but when a request comes there is no suitable adapter ...

anyone facing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can see it now, if the **contextPath** property isn't used then it is not set (is null) in jaxb2marshaller instance and following private method doesn't work as expected:

```
private boolean supportsInternal(Class<?> clazz, boolean checkForXmlRootElement) {
        if (checkForXmlRootElement && AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(clazz, XmlRootElement.class) == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(getContextPath())) {  // << -----
            String packageName = ClassUtils.getPackageName(clazz);
            String[] contextPaths = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(getContextPath(), ":");
            for (String contextPath : contextPaths) {
                if (contextPath.equals(packageName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        else if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(getClassesToBeBound())) {
            return Arrays.asList(getClassesToBeBound()).contains(clazz);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

so the JAXBElement<> trick doesn't work here :(